# Automatic source file preamble in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, plugins, licensing, comments

I would like to configure my VS2010 so that, every time a new source file is created, a comment preamble (which will contain a license) is included. Our immediate need is for C#, but it would be nice to predefine different comment blocks for different languages (which may be needed because of different comment syntaxes).

Is there a 3rd-party plugin for that?

Example:

```
/*
 * This software is licensed under the terms of Blah.
 * Use of this software is conditional to saying "Blah".
 */

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx