# Is there any way to define auto declarations in visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I was wondering, can i define an option (in visual studio) that will include automaticlly a code segment in each and every source code that i will create?
how can i do that?
thanks!

Comment: It's called a header file.

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716850/automatic-source-file-preamble-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: yes, but theres a way which i can duplicate it to every project that ill create ?

Comment: Option `/FI include-file` might be what you want?

Comment: Templates might be what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> an option (in visual studio) that will include automaticlly a code segment in each and every source code

Assuming "*include*" as `#include` and "*code segment*" to be source code then use option `/FL filename`.

In VS2010 it's in the project's configuration properties under "C/C++"-->"Advanced" tab.

For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx